# Convert SQL Server 2000 to 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server 2000 database and I want to convert it to SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to attach or restore a SQL 2000 backup into a SQL 2005 server.

Comment: thank you I tried it and I attached 2000 to 2005 and it worked well